# How to remove front axle?

Tags: axle, cv-joint, cv-boot

I want to replace a torn boot on my car's left front axle. In most of the videos I've watched a pry bar is used to remove the front axle. However, the service manual says to first remove the right front axle using a pry bar and then use a screwdriver and hammer to knock out the left front axle.
I was just wondering if that's really necessary or would it be possible to do it without having to remove both axles?

Comment: What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, it's a 1997 Y10 Nissan Wingroad.